# Getting new parameter after Python Toolbox gets executed

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, parameters, python-toolbox

I am trying to build a toolbox which would first take some inputs and execute some code and return me results. After the results I would like toolbox to ask me for new parameters so I can use these results.

Here is my idea with the code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import arcpy


class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = "toolbox"

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [Tool]


class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Tool"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""

        input_folder = arcpy.Parameter(
            name='input_folder',
            displayName='Input Folder',
            datatype='DEWorkspace',
            direction='Input',
            parameterType='Required')

        params = [input_folder]
        
        return params

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""
        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""

        #show me some results which i will make use.

        #execute something to get new parameter from user input and make operation.
        
        #and make the operation.
        return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [What is a Python toolbox?](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/a-quick-tour-of-python-toolboxes.htm) it says:

> Python toolboxes are geoprocessing toolboxes that are created entirely
> in Python. A Python toolbox and the tools contained within look, act,
> and work just like toolboxes and tools created in any other way.

In [Setting script tool parameters](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/setting-script-tool-parameters.htm) it says:

> Almost all tools have parameters, and you set their values on the tool
> dialog box or within a script. When the tool is executed, the
> parameter values are sent to your tool's source code. Your tool reads
> these values and proceeds with its work.

There is no option to interrupt the work of a tool and have new parameter values collected from the user of that tool.